# Is it possible to stop cell value link from one tab to another tab?

Tags: excel, tabs, cell

After searching for quite a while, I can't find the answer to this question, so if it's solvable, please feel free to answer :)

In the worksheet, I have two tabs: tab_A, tab_B.

tab_A has a list of data: A1, A2, A3, ...., etc.
tab_B is a copy of tab_A, through formula, so simply the cell value in tab_B is "=tab_A!A1", "=tab_A!A2", "=tab_A!A3", ... etc.

Now, here is the problem, if I want to add a data into the list in tab_A at location "A2", then what I do is that I add a new row after "A1", and type in the **new "A2"** value in the place where **old "A2"** was.

I expect the value in the tab_B at the location "**=tab_A!A2**" automatically changes to the new value that I just put in tab_A. **But**, instead, the value in that cell in tab_B changed to "**=tab_A!A3**".

Is there a way to link the cell values in two tabs that tab_B cell values stick to the cell values in tab_A at the location that I set?

Appreciate all the help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INDIRECT function. In a scheme like that:

[image]

in the cell C1 you add:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW(F1))
```

And autocomplete. The reference F1 it's to have a number that increase... Whit this code you can Insert and delete what you want and the second Table remain in Sync. If the second tab in in another table you add the reference before "A".